# How do I set up a jQuery animation for my on-hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I have some code that makes it so when a user hovers over a certain image it changes that image to another image.  Basically I want to add a jQuery animation or transition between these 2 events so that the image fills up vertically.  Here is the code I have so far:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'assets/banner-focus.png');
  }

  function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'assets/banner.png');
  }
</script>
<img src="assets/banner.png" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
```

Comment: You might want to look at [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), which can often be used to do these kinds of things without needing to write javascript code.

Comment: You can't use CSS to edit the image src value and I don't want to make a div and set the background to that image.

Comment: Then explain more concisely what you do want and show what you have tried. To my knowledge there is no change source animation per-se and to "fill up vertically" will almost certainly require other elements beyond just an image tag

Comment: The code I wrote already causes the source image to change.  I want the transition period between this to be a slide up type animation where new image slides over the old image.

Comment: You would have to hover a parent container then. As soon as you slide that up from under mouse...it triggers mouseout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the image.

```html
<img src="assets/banner.png" id="image">
```

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#image" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( this ).attr("src", "assets/banner-focus.png").animate({height: "20px"}, 500);
      }, function() {
        $( this ).attr("src", "assets/banner.png" ).animate({height: "500px"}, 500);
      }
    );
});
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y1s7d28j/4

Comment: That's literally the same thing I already wrote but with jquery

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question. Here's a working JSFiddle, you can customise animations as you please.
https://jsfiddle.net/y1s7d28j/4/
Answer also edited with update

Comment: Also a note is that I didn't specify sizes on the images for the fiddle. If you specify sizes, which I assume you will, things like the image changing when you move your mouse due to sizing, will not happen.

Comment: Yeah no worries I don't think I explained as well as I could either, anyways I looked at your code and it's pretty cool but I'm trying to have something that doesn't resize anything.

Basically I have Image 1 and once image 1 gets hovered on by the mouse then it should slowly fade into image 2.  The tricky part is though I want it to start fading at the very top and then work it's way down.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y1s7d28j/43/ This is another fiddle, with a mimic of a fadein and out, and no size changing, but I'm not the biggest fan of it. I'm not sure the best way to make it fade correctly, maybe add different timers to it so that it looks smoother, but the white flash annoys me. Not sure the best way to do this. I tried using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, but by default once opacity reaches 0, it'll give your image a `display: none` property, so your image will keep flashing, so it's only achievable using `animate()` with an `opacity` property.

Comment: Potentially add a timer to wait until the opacity is 0, then switch the src of the image? Might be an asynchronous issue, using `.then()` might fix the ordering as well

Comment: yeah that's good, the code you sent me gave me an idea just now ty